# A nice-looking WPF knob control source code?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, controls

I am trying to make some rotary knob with WPF and C#, .NET3.5; So right now what I am having is:

[image]

but instead, I really want to have something like these:

[image]
[image]

Anyone has any idea how I can make it look nicer? I am writing the WPF code from scratch. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you finished this control? I'm looking for a rotary knob control.

Comment: I really like the first one more than the others... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using SolidColorBrush right now. Play with [RadialGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.radialgradientbrush.aspx)  instead to achieve the look.

Answer (score 0):

You can create such an effect by finding a nice pictue of a knob, and then apply a rotatetransform on it.

If the picture contains the scale, you will need to edit that out to an other image, which can be under the knob picture.